# Tile id on grid from x/y position

Tags: java, algorithm, grid

(this image is not mine, but it helps ilustrate the point)

[image]

Give this grid with each tile beign 32x32 pixels, how can i calculate the tile ID where the mouse is?

In this case, mouse is on tile: 40.

Comment: What integers are given? What is height and width?

Comment: Is the position mentioned for green tile?Because if it is then should  it not   be 44 instead of 39?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say the current mouse position is (x,y) and the length of each small square is l(in the given case 32). Then, the grid x and y value will be given by:

```
gridX = x/l; //be sure it is integer division and not float
gridY = y/l; //
```

Then calculate the tile id on the basis of those values:

```
currentTileId = (boxesEachRow * gridY) + gridX + 1;
```

where boxesEachRow is the number of boxes along each row(here it is 8). The plus 1 is needed if you are treating the first box's id as 1 and not 0.